# How to set a custom message in the return path?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm sending automated emails using java mail to my colleagues in different states (all within our company). I set the `return path` as their manager's emails. In case the recipient's mail box is full, their manager would get an `undeliverable email` notification.

Is there any way I can customize that `undeliverable message`, so that their managers who receive  the `undeliverable notification`, would also get  instructions on how to handle those emails and "couch their subordinates" ?

I couldn't find any documentation on this. Is this even possible ?

Answer (score 1):

The undeliverable message is sent by your mail server.  Depending on the mail server you're using, you might be able to customize the returned message.

Answer (score 1):

For some cases you could try to enable the [mail.smtp.reportsuccess](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html) session property and use the [results](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/SendFailedException.html) to gather the [invalid addresses](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/SendFailedException.html#getInvalidAddresses--). Then use the [com.sun.mail.dsn](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/dsn/package-summary.html) to create a custom delivery status notification to send it to the return address.